# using gnuplot to read in - not output - a png image, or many, in one session - as an "overlay"

Tags: gnuplot

I want to read multiple png files - which themselves were created with gnuplot (`terminal png`) - in order to achieve an "overlay" - that is, a number of functions plotted together one on top of the other, with no background. This apparently could be done with gnuplot in one session.

I found this idea from the Linux Gazette article "Plotting the spirograph equations with 'gnuplot' ", from 2006 :

https://linuxgazette.net/133/luana.html

I am stuck on a number of error messages (vide infra) :

```
line 0: Bad data on line 1 of file [...]
line 0: warning: using default binary record/array structure
line 0: Too many using specs for this style
```

Looking for solutions, I read in the help pages ( http://gnuplot.info/docs_5.5/loc7742.html ) that gnuplot can read png images :

```
plot 'file.png' binary filetype=png
```

... and I have looked into using pngcairo instead of png itself. I am using eog to view the .png images. Here is sample code which generates the error above, and more if adjusted :

```
set size ratio -1
set nokey
set noxtics
set noytics
set noborder
set parametric
i2p = {0,1}*2*pi
set terminal png
t0 = 0
t1 = 1
#---------------------------------------------
# plot first function in the gnuplot session : 
#---------------------------------------------
test01(t) = exp(i2p*(2*t))
set output "solve_png_problem_15nov22a.png"
plot [t=t0:t1] 1*real(test01(t)),1*imag(test01(t)) lc 1
#---------------------------------------------------
# plot second function in the same gnuplot session :
#---------------------------------------------------
test02(t) = + 3*1.0**20 * exp(i2p*(-3*t+20/200. )) + 3*1.0**19 * exp(i2p*   (2*t+20/200.)) 
set output "solve_png_problem_15nov22b.png"
plot [t=t0:t1] 1*real(test02(t)),1*imag(test02(t)) lc 2
#------------------------------------------------------------
# last plotting to apparently "overlay" the two plots above :
#------------------------------------------------------------
set terminal png size 600,600
set output "solve_png_problem_15nov22_overlay.png"
set noparametric
plot "solve_png_problem_15nov22a.png", "solve_png_problem_15nov22b.png"
```

.... the reduced sample code is generated from the awk script supplement to the article - see it for detail :

https://linuxgazette.net/133/misc/luana/spirolang.awk.txt

The functions are nontrivial so they were kept in tact, as the associated settings might be causing the problem. The individual images look ok, so I think the problem is in the last plot command.

I read in the help pages that gnuplot can read png images :

```
plot 'file.png' binary filetype=png
```

... and also filetype=auto, and I have looked into using pngcairo instead of png itself, with no progress ; I have read the results of Google searches for the error messages. I have read the help pages on terminal, png, image, binary, and so on. I was expecting gnuplot to simply recognize the file was a png image that gnuplot itself generated, using the png terminal. What actually results is the error"Too many using specs for this style". For this, I have tried moving the position of the "binary filetype=png" in the code, which give the error "line 0: Bad data on line 1 of file [...]". I have also tried using programs outside gnuplot, such as montage and composite (ImageMagick).

gnuplot version 5.4 patchlevel 2
Ubuntu 22.04

post-answer update:
TL;DR : use svg terminal.

I saved a lot of grief by simply using the svg terminal. The original work must have been published before gnuplot got the svg terminal. I still need to work svg into the original script - but svg will make it a lot easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in GNUPLOT.

```
gnuplot<<EOF
set terminal png medium size 600,600 background rgb "white"
set size ratio -1
set nokey
set noxtics
set noytics
set noborder
set parametric
i2p = {0,1}*2*pi
t0 = 0
t1 = 1
#---------------------------------------------
# plot first function in the gnuplot session : 
#---------------------------------------------
test01(t) = exp(i2p*(2*t))
set output "solve_png_problem_15nov22a.png"
plot [t=t0:t1] 1*real(test01(t)),1*imag(test01(t)) lc 1
#---------------------------------------------------
# plot second function in the same gnuplot session :
#---------------------------------------------------
test02(t) = + 3*1.0**20 * exp(i2p*(-3*t+20/200. )) + 3*1.0**19 * exp(i2p*   (2*t+20/200.)) 
set output "solve_png_problem_15nov22b.png"
plot [t=t0:t1] 1*real(test02(t)),1*imag(test02(t)) lc 2
#------------------------------------------------------------
# last plotting to "overlay" the two plots above :
#------------------------------------------------------------
set output "solve_png_problem_15nov22_overlay.png"
plot \
[t=t0:t1] 1*real(test01(t)),1*imag(test01(t)) lc 1, \
[t=t0:t1] 1*real(test02(t)),1*imag(test02(t)) lc 2
EOF
```

First Result:

[image]

Second Result:

[image]

Combined Result:

[image]

Comment: Will gnuplot read multiple png files, as the script in the linked article suggests? Or is that obsolete?

Comment: I do not know. I am not that much of an expert in Gnuplot. I tried your commands and they did not work. So I went back to what I normally do.

Comment: I just noticed that, while I hard-wired the functions in the example above so it is clear, the original script plots numerous functions with all the variables changing slightly on each plot, then at the end is supposed to overlay them. I _could_ hand-write each function's parameters in, but the point is to examine the parameters rapidly. So in the example above, we see the first and last plots of about 15-20 plots.

Comment: Plotting raster images is described at http://www.gnuplot.info/demo_4.2/image.html. But I do not see anything about overlaying them. But there is really no need to create the separate images and then try to overlay them. You can plot multiple functions in the same plot as I did above.

Comment: I have a dilemma : should I [1] make a new post about only reading in png files, or [2] change this from "solved" to "unsolved" and pursue the reading of the png files? I apologize for this, because as I put the question, the problem was indeed solved - I just realized clearly now that it makes the work more complicated.

Comment: I suggest making a new post with a simple example about overlaying two existing PNG files. No other plotting. Just read the PNGs and overlay them.